# create pdf with a template pdf and add image, text, barcode, and complete field form , objective c, OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, pdf, barcode, form-fields

I am a newbie at Objective-C. I'm working on a project for a OSX. I have a pdf template  file with form fields, and I need to use it to **generate a new pdf adding some images, text, barcode, and complete form fields.**
I've been researching for working with PDFs, I'm trying to use `Quartz 2D, CGPDFContext`, and at this moment I managed to fill a new pdf with the page template, but I don´t know how to do to write on the fields forms and add other images.
How can I draw at specific point, text or image? or exist any library to manage pdf? and for generate barcode128? Thank you so much!

Comment: How do you know where to put the content you want to add? Does the template need to be a PDF?

Comment: The template I need to use as base for the new document its a PDF file, and I need to generate a new one document adding informations in specific point of the page (as image on the top x=50 y=50 for example), some contents for point, px, in the page, and the text for complete the text fields also for x,y coordinates if I could not write detecting form fields.

Comment: Concerning the form fields you should first check whether those are Acroform form fields or XFA forms. These two mechanisms are entirely different.

Comment: @mkl How I can know that? I think the form field has been created with acrobat XI

Comment: Either ask the source of the PDFs or inspect the PDFs (you might link some samples in your question for inspection by StackOverflow participants). If the source of the PDFs does not know, though, chances are they do not know what they are doing and, in case of updated pdf templates, send you files utilizing the other technique...

Comment: Ok, I found in the properties of the document pdf that PDF Producer and Aplication it's PDF Architect and another openOffice, instead of Adobe Live Cycle, so my pdf have AcroForm, I'm right? 
Any idea about how to access to this fields

Comment: If I could write in the form fields would be easier because I have several templates pdf to autofill with the same fields but these are in different positions.

Comment: and, is there some library to generate barcode 128? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a `CGPDFContext` you can draw whatever you want into it as you would with any other context. A simple solution is to create a `CALayer` (or a view and then access its layer) with the content you want and then to draw that layer into your PDF context.

Getting the editable text fields isn't so easy, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163313/extract-editable-fields-from-a-pdf-in-objective-c) might help.

If you can do away with the PDF template and do the whole thing as a view that you render into a PDF context that would be easier, but the process is generally the same once you know where you need to draw your additional text / graphics.

Comment: Thank you @Wain, I've already tried the code for get the fields but isnt worked propertly I can´t find XFA elements, and in the dictionary that found I only can recognize one of the fields elements. I didn´t know about CALayer, I'll try to used and let you know. I know where the elements to add have to go but I need to use over the template, I could draw all element in a view but after that how I merge the content into the template page?

Comment: In the question you said you had a context containing the PDF template so you can just draw over that (just ensure all of your view backgrounds are transparent).

Comment: Yes, I have a context with the PDF template, you mean I have to build a view with elements in the correct positions (and background transparent) and then draw the view to that context? the PDF template dont have all background transparent, have to have it?

Comment: I'm saying that using a view like that is a relatively easy option. The template doesn't need a transparent background as it is drawn first.

Comment: I'm trying to use something like 
`CGContextSelectFont (pdfContext, "Helvetica", 16, kCGEncodingMacRoman);`
`CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (pdfContext, kCGTextFill);`
`CGContextSetRGBFillColor (pdfContext, 0, 0, 0, 1);`
`const char *text = [prd_name UTF8String];`
`CGContextShowTextAtPoint (pdfContext, x+55,pageRect.size.height-(y+150+135) , text, strlen(text));` 
from [here](http://bit.ly/152OaEc)
and I've been able to write text on the template context!

Comment: I'm still trying to write to the pdf, because for coordinates, some fields may contain more than one line, is it possible to write inside a rectangle?

Comment: You can use a `UILabel` with a `clearColor` background or you can draw a string directly with `drawInRect:withAttributes:`.

Comment: Ok, Thanks @Wain, `UILabel` its for ios, isn't it?, tomorrow  I'll try that, with customView `NSView` and label in that view

Comment: Yes, that's for iOS, there are counterparts for OS X.

Comment: I've been able to manage a `NSView` and write elements in it with `drawInRect`. The pdf template is in `CGContextRef context` and now I need to add the `NSGraphicsContext` in that context, I tried to do this: `[_myView displayRectIgnoringOpacity:[_myView frame] inContext:(_bridge NSGraphicsContext *)(context)]; CGPDFContextEndPage(context);` but didn't work, what is wrong? How can I add the content of myView to the context where I have the template pdf

Comment: The rect should be the `bounds`, not the `frame`. Also, how did you create the context? Do you get any data out of the context?

Comment: Here for the template pdf `CGPDFDocumentRef template = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(urlTemplatePdf);`   and for the newContext `CGContextRef context = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(urlNewPdf, &rectTemplatePageBounds, NULL);` and start the context with the template page `CGPDFContextBeginPage(context, NULL);  CGContextDrawPDFPage(pdfContextNew, templatePage);`, also I tried to use CALayer in this context and I've been able to add a fill rect, but I don't know how to write string with correct encoding font in the layer, so I tried to use `NSView` and send the content to the context

Comment: and also tried `NSImage *imageW = [[NSImage alloc]initWithData:[_view dataWithPDFInsideRect:[_view bounds]]];`
`CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)[imageW TIFFRepresentation], NULL);`
`CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);`
`CGContextDrawImage(context, [_view bounds], imageRef);`
 but also generated a corrupted file

Comment: I can write the data in the view into a pdf file, with NSData, but in this case, I need merge somehow this new pdf file with the template pdf file

Comment: I tried also a `PDFView`, where I render the content of the template pdf OK, but how write over that view